# Using conditions to return specific rows

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-11g, query, case

From the following table i am trying to retrieve specific rows based on a criteria

```
+----+--------------+------+
| ID | UPDATED_DATE | TYPE |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 | 01/13        | P    |
|  1 | 02/13        | P    |
|  1 | 03/13        | P    |
|  2 | 01/14        | P    |
|  2 | 02/14        | W    |
|  2 | 03/14        | P    |
|  2 | 04/14        | W    |
|  2 | 05/14        | P    |
|  2 | 06/14        | P    |    
+----+--------------+------+

Expected rows:
+----+--------------+------+
| ID | UPDATED_DATE | TYPe |
+----+--------------+------+
|  1 | 01/13        | P    |
|  2 | 05/14        | P    |
+----+--------------+------+
```

Unique constraint on ID and UPDATED_DATE

Criteria:

> If type "W" exists in any of the rows for an ID then retrieve the next occurrence of 'P' after 'W'. If not retrieve the first occurrence of 'P'. If there are two 'W' for each ID then get the 'P' after the latest 'W'. I dont want to use window function as it is not supported in HSQL for unit testing.

I was successfully able to get the required row if i pass ID. But i want to run this for the entire table and get the necessary rows.

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN (
        SELECT
            MAX(UPDATED_DATE)
        FROM
            TABLE_NAME
        WHERE
            ID = '1'
            AND TYPE = 'W'
    ) IS NULL THEN
        (
            SELECT
                MIN(UPDATED_DATE)
            FROM
                TABLE_NAME
            WHERE
                ID = '1'
        )
    ELSE
        (
            SELECT
                MIN(UPDATED_DATE)
            FROM
                TABLE_NAME
            WHERE
                ID = '1'
                AND UPDATED_DATE > (
                    SELECT
                        MAX(UPDATED_DATE)
                    FROM
                        TABLE_NAME
                    WHERE
                        ID = '1'
                        AND TYPE = 'W'
                )
        )
END
FROM
   dual;
```

Comment: Databases do not "keep rows in a specific order".  You must define the `ORDER BY` in order to define "first","last","next","prior" rows.

Comment: Is the "order" defined by `UPDATED_DATE`? Can we assume that there is a `UNIQUE` constraint on `(ID, UPDATED_DATE)`?

Comment: You probably want to [merge your accounts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: And which DBMS is the target? Oracle or HSQL? Or both?